# How to pop back stack when button is pressed on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose screen in a fragment, and in that screen there is a button.

I want to dismiss the fragment/go back to previous screen when this button is pressed.

But I can't access any activity/fragment methods inside onClick.

How can I do that?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment @Inject constructor() : Fragment(){

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            this.setContent {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        //Dismiss fragment.
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(
                        "Click me"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner` inside any composable, and use `onBackPressed()` or navigate in an other way:

```
val onBackPressedDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.onBackPressedDispatcher
Button(
    onClick = {
        onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()
    },
) {
    Text(
        "Click me"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment @Inject constructor(

) : Fragment(){

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            this.setContent {

                val shouldDismiss = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                if (shouldDismiss) {
                    dismissFragment()
                }else{
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            shouldDismiss.value = true
                        },
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            "Click me"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun dismissFragment(){
        activity?.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```