# Compose Navigation pops a route before recomposing it again and looking for this route crashes the app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have the following use case:

1. Single `Activity` which uses `Jetpack Compose` + `Compose Navigation`.
2. There are 3 screens: `main`, `addresses` (child of `main`), and `address details` (child of `addresses`). `addresses` is defined using navigation sub-graph (in reality the navigation graph is much more complex so I want/need sub graphs), but the crash isn't related to it (i.e. it still occurs when I put all the routes 'inline').
3. `addresses` creates an `AddressesViewModel` scoped to its `NavBackStackEntry` and it as well as its children use the view model - children look for the `addresses` `NavBackStackEntry` to look up the same instance of the model (and it does have to be the same instance). The reason is that I want the view model to be destroyed when the `addresses` screen is popped.

This works fine when going deeper into the navigation graph; however, when going 'up' (popping the screens), popping the `addresses` screen and going to `main` causes a crash. The reason is that right after the pop the `addresses` `@Composable` is recomposed again, which looks up the view model, but at this point the back stack already doesn't have the `addresses` route, and looking up the back stack entry for `addresses` crashes.

An ugly workaround is to hook the view model to `main` screen, but it is too high up, and other modules (siblings of `addresses`) will also have it, which is undesired.

Another workaround is to catch the exception and don't render the content of the screen (but still render the `Scaffold` with the title etc. to prevent flickering. But this is also ugly.

I have a couple of questions:

1. I noticed that when using `Compose Navigation` the same screens are recomposed a few times (like 3, 4 or more) - why is that?
2. Why is the screen recomposed even after being popped?
3. I think I can't use the `viewModel` helper from `lifecycle-viewmodel-compose` because it scopes view models to the `Activity` / `Fragment` (i.e. a very broad scope I don't want), right? And even if it did scope it to the current route, this would effectively prevent me from sharing the view model for the whole graph (as each nav back stack entry would get its own instance).
4. Finally, how can I implement my use case without a crash, with property scoping using navigation back stack entries, without the aforementioned workarounds?

I created the sample using the latest Android Studio template for Jetpack Compose, here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09'

    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.2'
}
```

And here is the code (the view model lookup function causing the crash is at the end, its code is based on https://androidx.tech/artifacts/hilt/hilt-navigation-compose/1.0.0-alpha02-source/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/HiltViewModel.kt.html):

```kotlin
package com.example.nav_sample

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import androidx.navigation.navigation
import com.example.nav_sample.ui.theme.NavsampleTheme

const val main = "main"
const val addressesModule = "addressesModule"
const val addresses = "addresses"
const val addressDetails = "addressDetails"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            NavsampleTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = main) {
                    composable(main) {
                        ScaffoldScreen(
                            "Main screen",
                            onBack = { this@MainActivity.onBackPressed() },
                        ) {
                            Center {
                                Button(
                                    onClick = { navController.navigate(addressesModule) },
                                ) {
                                    Text("Addresses")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    navigation(route = addressesModule, startDestination = addresses) {
                        composable(addresses) {
                            val addressesViewModel: AddressesViewModel =
                                navController.scopedViewModel(route = addresses)
                            Log.wtf(
                                "NavSample",
                                "Route: '$addresses', AddressesViewModel instance: $addressesViewModel",
                            )

                            ScaffoldScreen(
                                "Addresses",
                                onBack = { navController.popBackStack() },
                            ) {
                                Center {
                                    Column {
                                        Button(
                                            onClick = { navController.navigate(addressDetails) },
                                        ) {
                                            Text("Address #1 details")
                                        }
                                        Button(
                                            onClick = { navController.navigate(addressDetails) },
                                        ) {
                                            Text("Address #2 details")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        composable(route = addressDetails) {
                            val addressesViewModel: AddressesViewModel =
                                navController.scopedViewModel(route = addresses)
                            Log.wtf(
                                "NavSample",
                                "Route: '$addressDetails', AddressesViewModel instance: $addressesViewModel",
                            )

                            ScaffoldScreen(
                                "Address details",
                                onBack = { navController.popBackStack() },
                            ) {
                                Center {
                                    Text("Address details")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScaffoldScreen(
    topBarTitle: String,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = onBack) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "back icon",
                        )
                    }
                },
                title = {
                    Text(text = topBarTitle)
                },
            )
        },
        content = { paddingValues ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(paddingValues)
            ) {
                content()
            }
        },
    )
}

@Composable
fun Center(
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        content = content,
    )
}

class AddressesViewModel : ViewModel()

@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavController.scopedViewModel(route: String): T {
    val viewModelStoreOwner = try {
        getBackStackEntry(route)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.wtf(
            "NavSample",
            "Thrown looking up route: '$route'",
            e,
        )

        throw e
    }

    val provider = ViewModelProvider(viewModelStoreOwner)

    return provider[T::class.java]
}
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69034777/3585796) on how to use `onBackPressed` inside any composable, without having to place it inside `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomposition happens because of transition animations. There's nothing you can do with this fact, your app should work fine with such recompositions.

Your local problem can be solved quite easily: inside `addresses` create a view model by calling `viewModel()` and inside `addressDetails` you will be able to get it with `scopedViewModel`.

View model scope is bind to the navigation route, as declared in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel).

Comment: Where does `scopedViewModel` come from? Code completion doesn't suggest anything so either this is something custom or I'm missing yet another lib.

Comment: @wujek it is an extension from your code `NavController.scopedViewModel` that originally caused the crash

Comment: Hah, yes, right. But how is it supposed to work if viewModel() from compose uses the activity / fragment as the owner, and scopedViewModel uses the nav graph entry?

Comment: @wujek `viewModel()` uses current navigation route as an owner, and activity only when there's no navigation

Comment: Thank it works. Could you tell me where it is documented that `viewMode()` works with nav routes? I just know this https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewmodel which says 'usually fragment or activity'. Anyways, this works, but in my app I actually need it to work with Koin, which doesn't support navigation yet, judging by the bugs.

Comment: Another way to make it work is to make `scopedViewModel` a normal function (not `@Composable` and wrap the return value in a `remember`, no idea whether this is good, though...

Comment: @wujek I haven't seen it in documentation, maybe because Compose Navigation is still in alpha. `remember` should work, but I think that `viewModel()` is much cleaner

Comment: @wujek I noticed the information on view model scope inside routes in [main navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel)